# How to convert the video picked from gallery into NSData using video url in ios?

Tags: objective-c, video, ios9, nsdata, phasset

I have shown all videos of gallery in collectionview using Photo framework. I have extracted the video urls from PHCachingImageManager (PHAsset lib) as given below:

```
[imageManager requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *vidInfo) {
        // Use the AVAsset avAsset
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
        AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        NSURL *vUrl=[self urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:videoPlayer];
        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",vUrl];

        if (url.length>0) {
            [videoInfo addObject:url];
        }
    }];
```

As I have to upload the selected video so I'm converting it into nsdata like below:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:selectedFileUrl  options:0 error:&error];
```

getting URLs like:`video url=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0165.MOV`

But I'm getting data as null always.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Thank you!!!

Comment: NSData * data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: selectedFileUrl]]; check this

Comment: Try with : `NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];`

Comment: thank you @NAVEENKUMAR. I tried what you guys said...still no success

Comment: then issue with ur url ... ur fetching the path of ur video is from locally... saved video..?

Comment: yes @NAVEENKUMAR they are local videos...recorded from a camera

Comment: this is code not enough can u provide upload section code.@sarita

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
  NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile::[NSURL URLWithString: selectedFileUrl]  options:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try with it

```
[imageManager requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *vidInfo) {
        // Use the AVAsset avAsset
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];
        AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        NSURL *vUrl=[self urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:videoPlayer];
        if (vUrl) {
            [videoInfo addObject:vUrl];
        }
    }];
```

Now you can get the data using : `NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];`